Populate select list of contact 2 based on selection of contact 1
I have two contacts, Schools and Teachers, linked by the Employee relationship. On a webform I want the schools as a select list and when on is selected to have the teachers of that school populated on another select list.
It works ok if autocomplete is used but it's not the best UI for what I want to do. Is it possible?
